# in python sort and group by common elements in a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, group, connected-components

I will try to express myself clearly.
Would anyone know how to order elements with common values in a list?
I made a drawing to explain it better. [image]
I have a list with several letters and their two number.

```
ev=(('A',(1,2)), ('M',(0,40)),('S',(17,32)),('Z',(2,7)),('K',(7,12)),('U',(40,18)),('R',(32,5)),('V',(28,47)),('X',(5,28)))
```

and after sort I would like get this result. but a don't knwo how find a efficient way.

```
grp=( ( ('A',(1,2)), ('Z',(2,7)), ('K',(7,12)) ), (  ('M',(0,40)), ('U',(40,18))  ), (  ('S',(17,32)), ('R',(32,5)), ('X',(5,28)), ('V',(28,47))  )
```

Comment: Are we guaranteed that every element "connects" to at most one element on each end (so that we can make simple linear chains)? If not, how should we handle the data? Does it matter what order the "chains" appear in the output? If so, what should their order be?

Comment: each letter has two numbers, that's for sure.
no letter is alone, it is necessarily connected to another letter.

Comment: What I mean is, could a letter connect to more than one other letter, on the same side?

Comment: ha, yes. a letter can be connected to two letters max.

Comment: Suppose you had a dictionary like `{0: ('M',(0,40)), 1: ('A',(1,2)), 2: ('Z',(2,7)), 5: ('X',(5,28)), 7: ('K',(7,12)), 17: ('S',(17,32)), 28: ('V',(28,47)), 32: ('R',(32,5)), 40: ('U',(40,18))}`. Given that, and a starting point such as the `('A',(1,2))`, do you see how you could extract the chain `( ('A',(1,2)), ('Z',(2,7)), ('K',(7,12)) )` step by step from the dictionary (and remove those entries)? If you repeat that process, do you see how that could give you all the chains? Can you see how to create the dictionary?

Comment: (I am giving hints because I think the question is not focused enough for a Stack Overflow question. It looks like solving the problem means following a straightforward series of steps.)

Comment: yes exactly. i had written a list but in fact it’s a dict.

Comment: i know how append the key/value from the dictionnary to a list, and remove them from the dictionnary. but the issue is to compare those elements.

Comment: So what shall happen to `ev=(('A',(1,2)), ('B',(2,3)), ('C',(2,4)))`?

Comment: in fact the numbers can only appear twice maximum. it’s a chain.

Comment: "but the issue is to compare those elements." No comparison is needed. The point of making such a dictionary is that, when you look up a number, it gives you the corresponding link, and you can look at that link to figure out the next number, and therefore the next link.

Comment: I wonder, why do you even want them in a list/tuple?

Comment: because it is about edges and their vertex. it is to have the list of several edge loops.

Comment: I just posted code I wrote when I first commented. I wasn't going to post it, but since nobody else has yet it's probably better than nothing. I haven't worked with graphs or linked lists much, so I'm not sure if it's the best/most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the nodes in a more suitable datatype - a dict. The keys are the first (tail) numeric values, and the values are the tuple values of `ev`, e.g. `('A', (1, 2))`. Just walk through the nodes until the next node doesn't exist. That's a group done. Walk through each node that has not been visited. That's all the groups done.

```py
ev = (('A', (1, 2)), 
      ('M', (0, 40)), 
      ('S', (17, 32)), 
      ('Z', (2, 7)), 
      ('K', (7, 12)), 
      ('U', (40, 18)), 
      ('R', (32, 5)), 
      ('V', (28, 47)), 
      ('X', (5, 28)))

# e.g. nodes[1] = ('A', (1, 2))
nodes = {tail: (letter, (tail, head)) for letter, (tail, head) in ev}

visited = set()
groups = []

for tail in nodes:
    if tail in visited:
        continue
    
    group = []
    while True:
        group.append(nodes[tail])
        visited.add(tail)
        
        # Get this node's head, which is the next node's tail.
        tail = nodes[tail][1][1]
        
        # There are no more nodes in the group, so append it to the list of groups
        if tail not in nodes:
            groups.append(tuple(group))
            break
    
groups = tuple(groups)

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
((('A', (1, 2)), ('Z', (2, 7)), ('K', (7, 12))), (('M', (0, 40)), ('U', (40, 18))), (('S', (17, 32)), ('R', (32, 5)), ('X', (5, 28)), ('V', (28, 47))))
```

Comment: this is exactely the expected result. I can see clearly the process. thank you a lot.